# SQL Query Remove Path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exploring the world of SQL and how to do query results. I am facing an issue for where I would like to display the **NodePath** but without the first two directories (folders). I just like to display the color, which can be anything from red to blue to silver.

**Example**

Current `/Database/Connections/RED/Default/Database`

Want `RED`

[image]

---

**Current Code**:

```
FROM [Backbone_AKING].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr]
WHERE NodeName = 'Database' AND EnvironmentName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY EnvironmentName asc
```

Comment: Need more information here - are you only looking for the three colors you mention?  Is it always the third subnode?  Is it always the third to last subnode?

Comment: The pattern I see is that is the third directory. It is not for colors I just replaced the original text to make it easier for human to read :D @DanField

So I just need to remove everything but the third directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the third position regardless of the length of any nodes:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (v VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT @t values ('/d/c/RED/d/dd'),('/dd/cc/SILVER/d/dd');

SELECT 
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(p3.s), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(p3.s))-1))
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(v, CHARINDEX('/',v, CHARINDEX('/', v, CHARINDEX('/', v, CHARINDEX('/', v)+1)+1)+1)-1)) as p3(s)
```

Following your example, it'd look like this:

```
SELECT 
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(p3.s), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(p3.s))-1))
FROM [Backbone_AKING].dbo.vw_CFGsvr
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(NodePath, CHARINDEX('/',NodePath, CHARINDEX('/',NodePath, CHARINDEX('/', NodePath, CHARINDEX('/', NodePath)+1)+1)+1)-1)) as p3(s)    
WHERE NodeName = 'Database' AND EnvironmentName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY EnvironmentName ASC
```

Explanation:  The cross apply is used to trim off everything after the third '/', including the '/'.  Then we reverse that, trim everything off after the first '/' in the reversed string, and reverse it again to get our result:

```
RED
SILVER
```

There are other ways to do this, and to be honest I'm not really sure any of them are elegant.  You could try to split up the `CROSS APPLY`s into more discrete items.  Short of writing a CLR Function to do this, I don't think you're going to find an elegant, foolproof way of doing this in SQL though.  SQL server string functions don't have any notion of "get me the nth occurence" or "split this string by this character" - CLR can do that easily.

Comment: Thank you this great and well explained answer @DanField. But sadly when I ran your code I got the following error: 

http://pastebin.com/AGDDSpSg

Comment: Those errors mean the column names don't match the view/table you're selecting from.

Comment: How can I fix this error? Sorry I am a bit lost my current code: http://pastebin.com/Cvz2YJ0P

Comment: Take out the `SELECT` on line 13.  Replace it with a `,` (comma).  You have a select statement with no FROM clause in that code.

Comment: I have did that (replace with ,) but my results are the same as before I added your new lines of code. I am missing something you think?

Comment: your last column should be the third item from `NodePath` if you removed that extra `SELECT` and added a comma right before the first `REVERSE`

Comment: Like this? http://pastebin.com/aXVMMaMf. For this will not work either, sorry for all the confusion on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79803/discussion-between-dan-field-and-theace).

Answer (score 0):

If the first directories are always the same, you can use the `substring` function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NodePath, 22, LEN(NodePath) - 22)
FROM [Backbone_AKING].[dbo].[vw_CFGsvr]
WHERE NodeName = 'Database' AND EnvironmentName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY EnvironmentName asc
```

Comment: I got an error that SUBSTRING needs 3 arguments so I added a 1:
 SELECT SUBSTRING(NodePath, 1, 22)

Comment: Sorry - I have edited the example. The errors in your pastebin have a different reason - those would be in your original query as well.

Comment: But the errors only started happening with the addition of SUBSTRING fucntion. What should I do?